# How to prevent “null” text in Binder using withConverter method on Vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8

How to prevent show text **`"null"`** when using [`Binder`](https://vaadin.com/api/8.0.1/com/vaadin/data/Binder.html) `withConverter` method

```
    TextField id = new TextField("Id");
    TextField name = new TextField("Name");

        Binder<Customer> b = new Binder<>();

        b.forField(id)
                .withConverter(Integer::valueOf, String::valueOf, "Invalid")
                .bind(Customer::getId, Customer::setId);
        b.forField(name)
                .bind(Customer::getName, Customer::setName);
        b.readBean(customer);
```

And the result is it:

[image]

> How do the conversion without losing the validation type?

Comment: You could do `id -> id == null ? "" : String.valueOf(id)` instead of just `String::valueOf`.

Comment: That's not working "String is not a functional interface".

Comment: Oh, you need to exchange the lambda parameter name because you already have a variable named "id". So try: `cid -> cid == null ? "" : String.valueOf(cid) `

Comment: You can use `TextField#setNullRepresentation`

Comment: Doesn't work because the signature expect an Integer value

Comment: The problem doing this `cid -> cid == null ? "" : String.valueOf(cid)` is I'm lost my validation type.

Comment: @Shirkam using `TextField#setNullRepresentation` works in conjuntion with  `.withValidator(new IntegerRangeValidator("Value must be greater than 0", 1, null))` because with `null` value in `maxValue` means for no limit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution using the vaadin API, thanks for the help [@Shirkam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6381179/shirkam)

```
    b.forField(id)
            .withConverter(Integer::valueOf, String::valueOf, "Invalid")
            .withNullRepresentation(0)
            .withValidator(new IntegerRangeValidator("Value must be greater than 0 ", 1, null))
            .bind(Customer::getId, Customer::setId);
    b.forField(name)
            .bind(Customer::getName, Customer::setName);
    b.readBean(customer);
```